# How to display just part of image on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/36Fmh/36/ I'm overlaying an image with text :

[image]

The image contains two states : a non-hover state and hover state :

[image]

How can the css be updated so that just the hover state is displayed ?

I can use jQuery to update the css to the required state on hover but im not sure what the css should be. I think I need to change the background-position attribute ?

Fiddle & code :

http://jsfiddle.net/36Fmh/36/

```
.qp_divSelect {
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 960px;
      height: 240px;
      background: url('http://i.imgur.com/83LeFIa.png') no - repeat;
      background - position: 0px - 25px;
      display: inline - block;
  }

 <div id="testId">

    <span class="qp_divSelect" style="color: #408800;" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('here')">

    <span style="position: absolute;font-weight: bold;color: white;padding-left: 22px;padding-top: 10px;font-size: 13px;top: -0px;padding-left: 22px;">Add</span>

    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is normally done by the element that has the background image being the width/height of just the part of the image that you want displayed and changing background position. in your case however, the div is 960x240, so it can't be done that way. The correct way to fix this is to not have the background image on a div that is 960x240.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `background-position` on pseudoclass `:hover`.

```
.qp_divSelect:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Here my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36Fmh/37/ (I had to adjust the width and height of the div).

**Edit**

I think I misunderstood your question. Is a possible solution for you to apply the sprite for the inner `span`?

E.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/36Fmh/38/

Answer (score 0):

Use :hover pseudo-selector.

```
.qp_divSelect:hover {
cursor: pointer;
width: 960px;
height: 240px;
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/hoveres-background.png') no-repeat;
 background-position: 0px -25px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is no jQuery needs.

Comment: not sure who is downvoting this, it's the correct answer.

Comment: it's clear in the question that the image being used is an image sprite. he doesn't need to change the image to a different image, he needs to change the background position. But that won't work because the div that has the background image is much larger than the background image itself.